# How to change coding of filenames (linux, ext4)

Tags: linux, bash

I've received 3670 files whose *names* are not UTF-8 encoded.  This makes typing them generally impossible, although some programs adapt and display them correctly.  It means I have lots of files like that display like this

```
?cole ?l?mentaire
```

instead of like this

```
école élémentaire
```

Although I can, for any given file, intuit the sense and rename it, I'd like to rename them in batch.  The trick is not batch rename, which is easy, but rather is automatically determining the target.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: The tags linux and bash mutually exclude the window related batch-file, removed.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/563427

Comment: As it's the *name* of the file that shows `?`, isn't this related to the file system type of the partition the files are stored on?

Comment: @DidierTrosset Nope, you can dump bytes at a filename, but if your bytes don't make sense in the current locale (not even fs), then it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: @jww I don't follow you, what in my question was unclear?  I was expecting not to be pointed at a tool but rather to see suggestions (as @DevSolar) on how to approach the problem.  That Nazar554 proposed a link that neatly solved the problem is a nice plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although I can, for any given file, intuit the sense and rename it, I'd like to rename them in batch. The trick is not batch rename, which is easy, but rather is automatically determining the target.

- Get the filenames into a file: `find <directory> > filelist.txt`
- Check the encoding of the filenames: `file filelist.txt` / `hexdump -C filelist | less`

  - Shamelessly advertising [encoding.rootdirectory.de](http://encoding.rootdirectory.de) for side-by-side character tables to figure out exactly which encoding you're looking at
- Get a second list of filenames in UTF-8 encoding: `iconv -f <source-encoding> -t utf-8 filelist.txt > filelist-utf8.txt`

---

...and at this point @Nazar554 posted [this link to a ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/563427) in a comment, using the purpose-built `convmv` command, and made it pointless to continue this answer with instructions on how to read from the two filelists line-by-line to create the required `mv` commands. :-D

The first two bullet points will still help you figuring out the source encoding, though.

Comment: I'm upvoting this response because it's clear and correct and, probably, easier to remember.  But @Nazar554 deserves at the very least a shout-out for the excellent [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/563427) link.

Comment: @jma: The shout-out is right in the answer. I don't steal other user's thunder, and have upvoted the ServerFault answer.

Comment: @jma: Be aware that a "production quality" implementation of my suggestion would have to cater for e.g. newlines in file names and stuff like that. This *can* be done (e.g. using `file ... -print0` and associated trickery) but is usually overkill for a one-shot solution *provided* the one who named those files was *halfway* sane with regards to naming conventions. As always, keep a backup. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the answer [linked to above](https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames/563427#563427):

1. Change to the directory containing the files in question:

   ```
   cd myfiles
   ```
2. Determine the encoding of the file names:

   ```
   ls | file -
   ```
3. List the available encodings of `convmv`, and pick the one corresponding to point 2:

   ```
   convmv --list
   ```
4. Execute a dry-run of the filename encoding conversions to UTF-8:

   ```
   convmv -f xxxx -t utf8 .
   ```
5. Perform the filename encoding conversions to UTF-8:

   ```
   convmv --notest -f xxxx -t utf8 .
   ```

Of course, it's needed to first install `convmv` with `sudo apt-get install convmv` on Linux, or `brew install convmv` on Mac.